# Elgato Systems GmbH Game Capture HD60 S+ Not Working with USB3.0

Tags: 20.04, usb, video, stream, capture

I have two Ubuntu installations and my newer laptop can connect properly with Video Capture card on USB3.0, but desktop can only connect with USB2.0. Any ideas as to what the issues might be connecting USB3.0 for this card on my desktop?

```
Linux comp1 5.11.0-38-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 28 20:41:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comp1 - USB3.0 (works):

Bus 002 Device 028: ID 0fd9:006a Elgato Systems GmbH Game Capture HD60 S+

/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 28, If 4, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 28, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 28, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 28, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 28, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M

[94726.756256] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
[94726.776799] usb 2-1: LPM exit latency is zeroed, disabling LPM.
[94726.777495] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fd9, idProduct=006a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[94726.777507] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[94726.777513] usb 2-1: Product: Game Capture HD60 S+
[94726.777517] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Elgato
[94726.777521] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 000656BD81000
[94726.785555] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.10 device Game Capture HD60 S+ (0fd9:006a)
[94726.831531] uvcvideo 2-1:1.0: Entity type for entity Input 1 was not initialized!
[94726.831792] input: Game Capture HD60 S+: Game Capt as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input37
[94726.833979] hid-generic 0003:0FD9:006A.001E: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Device [Elgato Game Capture HD60 S+] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2



Linux comp2 5.11.0-40-generic #44~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 26 18:07:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comp2 - UBS3.0 (does not work):

Bus 011 Device 002: ID 0fd9:006a Elgato Systems GmbH

/:  Bus 11.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M


[ 5320.978128] usb 11-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 5320.995251] usb 11-1: LPM exit latency is zeroed, disabling LPM.
[ 5321.185177] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: WARN Cannot submit Set TR Deq Ptr
[ 5321.185189] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: A Set TR Deq Ptr command is pending.
[ 5321.195242] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xcffe9400 flags=0x0020]
[ 5321.195268] usb 11-1: config index 0 descriptor too short (expected 522, got 10)
[ 5321.195283] usb 11-1: config 1 descriptor has 1 excess byte, ignoring
[ 5321.195291] usb 11-1: config 1 has 0 interfaces, different from the descriptor's value: 5
[ 5321.395365] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xcffe7400 flags=0x0020]
[ 5321.395401] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xcffe7440 flags=0x0020]
[ 5321.395429] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xcffe7480 flags=0x0020]
[ 5321.395455] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xcffe74c0 flags=0x0020]
[ 5321.395479] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xcffe7540 flags=0x0020]
[ 5321.395503] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xcffe7500 flags=0x0020]
[ 5321.395527] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xcffe7580 flags=0x0020]
[ 5321.395552] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xcffe75c0 flags=0x0020]
[ 5321.395564] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 0 comp_code 4
[ 5321.395577] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000000cfff8180 trb-start 00000000cfff81a0 trb-end 00000000cfff81c0 seg-start 00000000cfff8000 seg-end 00000000cfff8ff0
[ 5331.570638] usb 11-1: string descriptor 0 read error: -110
[ 5331.570659] usb 11-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fd9, idProduct=006a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 5331.570669] usb 11-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[ 5336.690557] usb 11-1: can't set config #1, error -110


Comp2 - USB2.0 (works):

Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0fd9:006b Elgato Systems GmbH Game Capture HD60 S+

/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/5p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 4, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M



[ 5418.049282] usb 11-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 5426.893039] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 5427.268949] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0fd9, idProduct=006b, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 5427.268966] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[ 5427.268975] usb 1-3: Product: Game Capture HD60 S+
[ 5427.268982] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Elgato
[ 5427.268987] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 000656BD81000
[ 5427.331207] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.10 device Game Capture HD60 S+ (0fd9:006b)
[ 5427.486285] uvcvideo 1-3:1.0: Entity type for entity Input 1 was not initialized!
[ 5427.486534] input: Game Capture HD60 S+: Game Capt as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input41
[ 5427.560595] hid-generic 0003:0FD9:006B.000B: hiddev2,hidraw4: USB HID v1.01 Device [Elgato Game Capture HD60 S+] on usb-0000:00:12.2-3/input2
```

---

Update for the information:

**Comp1**:

```
BIOS: N22ET65W (1.42 )
MBoard: 20L7CTO1WW 
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz
```

**Comp2**:

```
BIOS: 1604 
Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: M5A97 EVO
    Version: Rev 1.xx
CPU: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1100T
```

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.9Gi       5.2Gi       4.0Mi       8.6Gi        13Gi
Swap:          15Gi          0B        15Gi
```

**Distro on both: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**

Comment: What processor in computer #1? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h` on computer #2, and tell me the EXACT make/model of the computer or motherboard. What version Ubuntu on both machines?

Comment: BIOS: N22ET65W (1.42 ) - Comp 1
BIOS: 1604 - Comp 2
Board: 20L7CTO1WW - Comp 1
Board: M5A97 EVO - Comp 2
Proc: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz - Comp 1
Proc: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1100T - Comp 2

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS - Both

Mem on comp 2 free 5.4 Gi

Comment: Your comment, although full of information, was confusing to read. Please do this... edit your question and for both computers, show me CPU info, `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, `free -h`, and make/model # of computer or motherboard. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure when you supply requested data, that you ping the requestor with a comment that starts with @heynnema (in my example), or we'll never see your updates.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**Computer #1**

---

**BIOS**

Lenovo 20L7CTO1WW (T480s (type 20L7, 20L8) Laptop (ThinkPad))

You have BIOS version 1.42 dated 2020/07/07, and there's a newer BIOS available, version 1.48 dated 19 Nov 2021, and can be downloaded [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t480s-type-20l7-20l8/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI).

**Computer #2**

---

**BIOS**

ASUS M5A97 EVO Version: Rev 1.xx

1604 is current.

**Memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.